# dispatch_semaphore_wait not triggered after timeout

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I want to build an NSOperation that has a timeout of 10 seconds after it begins and could be ended by another thread at any point through an event. I also use an NSOperationQueue for managing more operations like this and it can only compute one at a time(maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1). For this I have thought about an implementation using `dispatch_semaphore`'s as it follows:

```
@implementation CustomOperation

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore;
-(void) main {
    @autoreleasepool {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(shouldFinishWaiting:) name:@"myCustomEvent" object:nil];

        semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

        [self doStuff];

        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)));
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"myCustomEvent" object:nil];
    }
}


-(void) shouldFinishWaiting {
    NSLog(@"[WatchOperation]: Should finish waiting! %@", self);
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}

@end
```

The problem I have is that once in many times when an user starts the application the first operation would not finish until the event gets triggered(and this could happen after 30 mins). The timeout would not be taken in consideration. I noticed this on logs from some users so I wasn't able to reproduce it. What could go wrong so that the `dispatch_semaphore_wait` fails to execute?

Later edit: I mistakenly thought that the `-doStuff` is async. It seems it is not.I replaced it with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), ^{ 
    [self doStuff]; 
});
```

, but the operation was already on the serial queue 'user initiated'. As I can see it creates another concurent thread, will that happen every time? Is this safe?

Comment: What is `-doStuff`? Is it asynchronous? That is, does it start something on a secondary thread or dispatch queue and then return immediately without waiting for that something to complete? If it's synchronous, then your semaphore is useless.

Comment: It is asynchronous. It starts an action on the same thread and it ends, the semaphore waiting for an event from another thread.

Comment: ok, my bad... it seems that the -doStuff was synchronous :(

Comment: please check updated answer.

Comment: Yes, queues and threads are different entities. A queue would be serviced by multiple threads (generally belonging to the same priority group). In your case, the same thread can never pick the task [self dostuff] since it is blocked on the semaphore, which would thus be picked up by a different thread. However, during extreme resource shortage, the OS might not be able to spawn a different thread, but that's still rare. Also, you should use a FIFO queue in this case since the GCD threads are generally concurrent.

Comment: what will then happen if the os will not create a different thread for that task? they will run on the same thread, right?

Comment: Not in your current implementation. You have just 1 thread that is blocked on the semaphore. That thread MUST complete executing the entry function before it can pick up a new task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think dispatch semaphore can go wrong. Maybe your -doStuff is taking too much time. Make sure you are doing the following: 
1. The method `[self doStuff];` is async and it dispatches to a DIFFERENT thread than the current one (dispatching to current thread doesn't really make sense if you want the 10 second timeout using the semaphore). 
2. Make sure you keep checking for self.isCancelled in -doStuff.

Also, I would suggest that you take a slightly different design approach for your requirements (if I understand them correctly) -- 
1. Your NSOperation can always be cancelled from any external thread my calling cancel on the object, so there is no need for a complex NSNotification-based approach, just check for isCancelled and override the -cancel method. 
2. For the 10 second timeout, you can use the semaphore approach, but just have a DIFFERENT thread doing the semaphore wait. That thread can then cancel your task from within after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your semaphore won't stay a global variable...

Depending on whether you are using 32 or 64 bit, NSEC_PER_SEC could be a 32 bit value, which overflows and turns into something negative when multiplied by 10. Replace 10 by 10.0. Might fix the problem, might not do anything at all.

Comment: As ive seen from logs it seems that at some point the dispatch_semaphore_wait triggers the operation to continue, but after a much longer time than expected

Answer (score 0):

@selector(shouldFinishWaiting:) should be @selector (shouldFinishWaiting). No colon because the method has no arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but is that the reason :D?